# pass javascript variables to python flask

Tags: python, variables, flask

I'd like to pass variables (e.g. window.screen.width) from the HTML page to flask.
How can I do that?

(And I really need that variable in flask, I can't fix it by having a responsive webpage)

Comment: Flask is a back-end engine, it is not meant to take variables from the front-end before rendering pages for the front-end. By the sound of it, your issues is entirely front-end based. Try seeking CSS/JS solutions instead.